# Looping function optimisation - currently running slow

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if anyone can offer advice on the following looping code I have compiled. When I run this from my laptop it processes really quickly within 2-3 seconds however I run this on a works computer and it runs really slowly and takes 10+ minutes to do the 3000-4000 rows.

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Cell, Rng, Table As Range

    'Turn off Screen updating - Speed process - Turn back on prior to Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("Del Data").Select

    'Validate Data Exists in Range
    If Range("B3").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Data Available to calculate." & vbNewLine & _
        "Please ensure first consigment number is pasted in cell B3." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "For assistance please refer to user manual supplied with file.", _
        vbCritical, "Error Compiling Stop Calculator"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Identify Last possible row and set Range
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set Rng = Range("B3:B" & LastRow)

    '**********************************
    ' Calculate unique values  
    '**********************************
    For Each Cell In Rng
        Cell.Offset(0, 33).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value, 3))
        Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value, 3))
        Cell.Offset(0, 35).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 17).Value, 3))
        Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value = Trim(Cell.Offset(0, 21).Value)

        Cell.Offset(0, 36).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 33).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value
        Cell.Offset(0, 37).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value
    Next 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Exit Sub
```

Is there any possible way to improve the code above to allow this to speed up? I understand as this is running fine on my laptop it might just be a computer issue with my works PC although specs of the PC is really good and definitely up to the task.

Comment: Side note: (1) If you declare `Dim Cell, Rng, Table As Range` then only `Table` is declared as `Range` the first 2 variables remain `Variant`. You need to specify a type for **every** variable like `Dim Cell As Range, Rng As Range, Table As Range`. (2) Avoid using `.Select` and `ActiveSheet` this is bad practice and you could run into errors. Therefore read [VBA Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices).

Comment: (1) Are there any references to other workbooks? (2) Are there differences in calculation mode (manual/automatic)? (3) Are there any differences in Office version? Update both to the same build.

Comment: Thanks @Peh I will update the DIM, I assumed it would set all as range but it is good to know. The code is new and I set .Select and ActiveSheet as a quick draft before amending to the actual code I would want (I do this to ensure I have the loops correct first). No reference to other workbooks, calculation mode not needed as the VBA does the calculation and posts the value. My laptop is latest 2017 VBA but works computer is 2010 (Unable to upgrade to match my laptop) but this was created originally on works computer and put on laptop as a way to work from home

Comment: Try also setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before your loop

Comment: That's a big difference.  Do you run it locally on your laptop, but over a network at work?  There are issues which @Peh has pointed out, but I can't see that alone giving such a big difference in timing.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Thanks At present it is running locally on both machines, Work network at the moment is down due to recent issues. I have just been advised it may be an issue with 32-bit vs 64-bit excels which I find strange?

Comment: Perhaps an issue relating to the amount of cores available for calculation. Try to see using ctrl + alt + del what the CPU usage and memory usage is on both machines and if there is a significant difference between the two.

Comment: You could switch .Value to .Value2

Comment: For some reason deleting all the data sving and restarting had the worksheet process the loops with no issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

?

```
Dim i As Long

'**********************************
' Calculate unique values
'**********************************
With ActiveSheet
    For i = 3 To LastRow
        .Cells(i, 35).Value = Trim$(Left$(.Cells(i, 7).Value, 3))
        .Cells(i, 36).Value = Trim$(Left$(.Cells(i, 9).Value, 3))
        .Cells(i, 37).Value = Trim$(Left$(.Cells(i, 19).Value, 3))
        .Cells(i, 40).Value = Trim$(Left$(.Cells(i, 23).Value, 3))

        .Cells(i, 38).Value = .Cells(i, 36).Value & .Cells(i, 35).Value & .Cells(i, 40).Value
        .Cells(i, 39).Value = .Cells(i, 36).Value & .Cells(i, 36).Value & .Cells(i, 40).Value
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Answers posting code without any text/comments (e.g. about what you did/changed and why) are a very bad practice and not really helpful. Please refer to [answer].

Answer (score 0):

i used a VBA array to make things faster, and a bit to tweaking here and there.

I didn't test the code, so make a copy of your data first.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()


'Sheets("Del Data").Select
With thisworkbook.Sheets("Del Data")

    'Validate Data Exists in Range
    If .Range("B3").Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "No Data Available to calculate." & vbNewLine & _
        "Please ensure first consigment number is pasted in cell B3." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "For assistance please refer to user manual supplied with file.", _
        vbCritical, "Error Compiling Stop Calculator."
        Exit Sub
    End If


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'i declared the variables after the condition to exit sub
    Dim LastRow As Long, i&
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RngArray() 'is a variant type array, used to fast up the process

    'Identify Last possible row and set Range
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2)) '"B3:B" & LastRow)

    RngArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2 + 39)).Value2


    '**********************************
    ' Calculate unique values
    'beware: Cell.Offset(0, 0) is converted in my coding to RngArray(i, 1)
    '**********************************

    For i = 3 To LastRow

        'Cell.Offset(0, 33).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value, 3))
        RngArray(i, 34) = Left(Trim(RngArray(i, 6)), 3)

        'Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value, 3))
        RngArray(i, 35) = Left(Trim(RngArray(i, 8)), 3)

        'Cell.Offset(0, 35).Value = Trim(Left(Cell.Offset(0, 17).Value, 3))
        RngArray(i, 36) = Left(Trim(RngArray(i, 18)), 3)

        'Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value = Trim(Cell.Offset(0, 21).Value)
        RngArray(i, 39) = Left(Trim(RngArray(i, 22)))

        'Cell.Offset(0, 36).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 33).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value
        RngArray(i, 37) = RngArray(i, 35) + RngArray(i, 34) + RngArray(i, 39)

        'Cell.Offset(0, 37).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 34).Value & Cell.Offset(0, 38).Value
        RngArray(i, 38) = 2 * RngArray(i, 35) + RngArray(i, 39) 'OP readed twice same Cell , i used *2, might be OP miss

    Next i

    'write back values to sheet
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2 + 39)).Value2 = RngArray

End With


Set Rng = Nothing
Erase RngArray

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlAutomatic
End With
Exit Sub
```